# What order are annotated methods called in for an annotated Controller class in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

so i have a couple @ModelAttribute methods, a couple @RequestMapping methods and an @InitBinder method. I know the model attribute will be called before the request mapping but which one is called first? the model attribute or the init binder?

Comment: Add a break point in each method.